# Conditionally extracting digits from patterns from strings in R

Tags: r, regex, for-loop, dplyr, stringr

I'd like to extract digits from strings if the string has both a "..1.." and "..0.." pattern in it. If the string has both these patterns, I'd like to extract all digits that are a part of a "..(any digit).." pattern in that string.

The result of my attempt is different from my expected result, see below code.

```
 # Load packages
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

# Load toy dataset 
film = data.frame(var=c("grey..0..yellow..1..", "grey..0..brown..1..", "grey0brown1", "grey..a..brown..3..", "grey..a0..red..1...", "grey..0..blue..1...brown..2..", "3grey..0..purple..1...brown..2..", "3grey..0..purple..1...brown..2..brown..3.."))


# Attempt 
for (i in film$var)
  if(str_detect(i, "[.][.]0[.][.].+[.][.]1[.][.]")){               # if entries feature both "..0.." AND "..1.." patterns 
film$var2 = str_extract_all(i, "([.][.][:digit:][.][.])+") %>%     # extract any  "..(any digit).." patterns 
  str_extract_all(., "[:digit:]+")                                 # further extract the digits out of those already extracted patterns     
  }


#Expected result 
film$expected_var = c("0, 1", "0, 1", "", "", "", "0, 1, 2", "0, 1, 2", "0, 1, 2, 3")
```

Thought it'd be nice to use stringr as it's makes for very readable code. Not sure where I've gone wrong though. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm horrible with regex --- so I'm sure there's a better way. Here's one approach:

```
x <- str_extract_all(film$var, "(?<=\\.\\.)\\d(?=\\.\\.)")
newvar <- sapply(x, function(y) paste0(y, collapse = ', '))
newvar[!(grepl("0", newvar) & grepl("1", newvar))] <- ""
cbind(film, newvar)

                                         var expected_var     newvar
1                       grey..0..yellow..1..         0, 1       0, 1
2                        grey..0..brown..1..         0, 1       0, 1
3                                grey0brown1                        
4                        grey..a..brown..3..                        
5                        grey..a0..red..1...                        
6              grey..0..blue..1...brown..2..      0, 1, 2    0, 1, 2
7           3grey..0..purple..1...brown..2..      0, 1, 2    0, 1, 2
8 3grey..0..purple..1...brown..2..brown..3..   0, 1, 2, 3 0, 1, 2, 3
```

Please let me know if this would meet your needs. I hope someone can provide a better answer.